# ArrayList <? super Number> and Double

Tags: java, generics

From http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ103:

> A wildcard with a lower bound looks like " ? super Type " and stands
>   for the family of all types that are supertypes of Type , type Type
>   being included. Type is called the lower bound .

So why

```
ArrayList<? super Number> psupn1 = new ArrayList<Number>();
psupn1.add(new Double(2));
```

compiled?

Double is not supertype of Number but subclass of Number...

Edit 1:

```
    ArrayList<? super Number> pextn1 = new ArrayList<Number>();
    psupn1.add(new Integer(2));
    psupn1.add(new Double(2));
    psupn1.add(new Float(2));
    for(Number n : psupn1){ // [Invalid] Number should be change to
    // Object even if I can only add subtype of Number??

    }
```

Comment: This might help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *add* a `Double` to that, because whatever the type parameter `E` is, it's guaranteed to be either `Number` or a supertype... which means you can definitely convert from `Double` to `E`. You wouldn't be able to do:

```
Number x = psupn1.get(0);
```

though.

Think about it, and try to create lists which would logically break this. For example, you can't use:

```
// Invalid
ArrayList<? super Number> psupn1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
psupn1.add(new Double(2));
```

because `Integer` *isn't* either `Number` or a supertype - it's a subclass. You can write:

```
// Valid
ArrayList<? extends Number> psupn1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

... because that's the other way round. At that point you can write:

```
Number x = psupn1.get(0);
```

because any element in the list is guaranteed to be convertible *to* `Number`. It's all about which way the conversions are required - *to* the generic type parameter or *from* it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation but can you explain me the "Edit 1" I just wrote, I still don't understand

Answer (score 5):

Maurice Naftalin and Philip Wadler explain it best in [Java Generics and Collections](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527754/):

> The Get and Put Principle: use an
>   extends wildcard when you only get
>   values out of a structure, use super
>   wildcard when you only put values into
>   a structure, and don't use a wildcard
>   when you both get and put.

Comment: +1 This rule is easy to understand!

Comment: "PECS" (producer extends, consumer super)

Answer (score 0):

For any type `X`, you can only retrieve `X` from `List<? extends X>` and only insert `X` into `List<? super X>`. But you can both insert and retrieve `X` to/from `List<X>`.

Here you can insert any `Number` into this instance of `List<? super Number>`, and of course all of your examples, `new Integer(2)`, `new Double(2)` etc. are instances of `Number`, so they can be put into the list.

But if you call `.get()` on this list you cannot assume it contain only numbers. To see why note that this is legal java code:

```
    List<Serializable> serializables = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
    serializables.add("You know String implements Serializable!");
    List<? super Number> list = serializables;
    Object o = list.get(0);  // Object is your best guess about the result's type
```

Also note that there is nothing magical in `.get()` and `.add()`. Actually all this happens because if you inspect the definition of `java.util.List<E>` you can see that `.get()` returns an `E` while `add()` takes an `E` as a parameter.

Comment: wow, does it mean that Serializable is a subclass of Number?

Comment: Nope, actually because Serializable is a *superclass* of Number!

Answer (score 0):

What `List<? super Number>` says is: we guarantee you can put a `Number`, or any subclass of `Number`, into this `List`. It doesn't make any guarantees about what you get out of it. Consider:

```
void <T> addToList(List<? super T> list, T... things) {
    for (T t: things) {
        list.add(t);
    }
}

void <T> printList<List<? super T> list) {
    for (T t: list) { // doesn't compile
        System.out.println(t);
    }

    for (Object o: list) { // just fine
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

    // 1, 2.0f, 3.0 autoboxed to Integer, Float, Double
    addToList(objects, "a string", new Object(), 1, 2.0f, 3.0); // just fine
    printList(objects);

    List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
    addToList(numbers, "a string", new Object(), 1, 2.0f, 3.0); // doesn't compile
    addToList(numbers, 1, 2.0f, 3.0); // just fine
    printList(numbers);

    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    addToList(ints, 1, 2.0f, 3.0); // doesn't compile
    addToList(ints, 1, 2, 3); // just fine
    printList(ints);
}
```