# Generics - lower/ upper bound wild card behaviour?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to understand the behavior of lower as well as upper bound wild cards.

Got an issue while trying to compile the below code.

```
Collection<? extends Object> c = new ArrayList<Object>();
c.add(new Object()); // Compile time error
```

For figuring out the issue, I simply tried the lower bound wild card as well. Fortunately or unfortunately, code compiles fine but created so many confusion.

```
Collection<? super Object> c = new ArrayList<Object>();
 c.add(new Object()); // Compiles fine
```

Can somebody explain me, how these two code snippets are working. It would be great if someone can provide additional examples/links.

Please correct me if I did something wrong above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JornVernee Agree it is related to PECS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?` means an "unknown type".

`Collection<? extends Object>` represents a collection of some type of object. This "some type" can be any type that is a subclass of `Object` or `Object` itself. Which type exactly? The compiler does not know.

When you try to add a new `Object` to the collection, you can't. This is because the collection's type is not known. It can be an `ArrayList<String>`. It can be a `HashSet<Integer>`. So the compiler says

> "What if the collection is `ArrayList<String>`? You can't put an `Object` in there!"

Basically, the compiler is too cautious to let you do that.

---

`Collection<? super Object>` represents a collection of some type of object. This "some type" can be any type that is a superclass of `Object` or `Object` itself. It can only be one thing here - `Object`, because `Object` does not have a superclass. That's why you can add a new `Object` to the collection.

Even if `Object` has a superclass, you would still be able to add a `new Object()`. Let's call the superclass of `Object` `MyClass`. Now, the collection can either be a collection of `MyClass` or `Object`. Whichever it is, you will be able to add an `Object` to it.

Comment: I fully understood the part regarding `Collection<? extends Object>` and it makes sense. But what is the reason that is *DOES* accept *ANY* `SupersClass` or the `Object` class itself in case of `Collection<? super Object>`?

Comment: That's just what ? super Object means. If A extends B, you can add B to a collection of A. It's the same thing here. @Yahya

Comment: @JornVernee oh it's a typo. I mean you can add A to a collection of B.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks, I figured out what you meant. I think your last paragraph explains it well enough. But it's tricky to see in your head.

Answer (score 0):

Let's change the class type to make it a bit more understandable. Your first example changed to `Number`

```
Collection<? extends Number> c = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

Means that there are `?` objects from type `Number`. So it could be anything that `extends Number` e.g. `Integer`, `Double`, `Float`, `BigInteger` etc. So you can not guarantee what kind of `Number` Object resides in the list since

```
List<Integer> // only allows Integer
List<Double> // only allows Double
List<Float> // only allows Float
```

That's why you can not add anything to `<? extends Number>` because it could be either one of the Lists above.

The other way around is for `<? super Number>`.
This means that every object inside the List is an ancestor of `Number`. In this case you are allowed to add anything from supertype/type of `Number`. You guarantee with `? super Number` that everything inside is a `Number`.

But what you can not guarantee is the actual type e.g.

```
list.get(0); // is a Number, but could be a Integer
list.get(1); // is a Number, but could be a Float
list.get(2); // is a Number, but could be a Double
```

tl;dr use `extends` for reading and `super` for adding.

And here is a graph from the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

[image]

Here is an explanation from Jon Skeet for `<? super Number>`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8083260/4467208

Comment: The section about `? super` needs work. You've got most of it backwards. `Integer`, `Float`, and `Double` aren't possible if the bound is `? super Number`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman But those types are a `Number`. They don't necessarily need to be a super type.

Comment: `Integer` is a subclass of `Number`. `? super Number` matches *superclasses* (or `Number` itself). The only superclass of `Number` is `Object`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes and these are Numbers e.g. http://ideone.com/fu5Rvt